# flatMap on a map gives error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 1

Tags: scala

I have a map m

```
val m = Map(1->2, 3->4, 5->6, 7->8, 4->4, 9->9, 10->12, 11->11)
```

Now i want a map whose keys are equal to the values. So i do this

```
def eq(k: Int, v: Int) = if (k == v) Some(k->v) else None
m.flatMap((k,v) => eq(k,v))
```

This gives me the error

```
error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 1
m.flatMap((k,v) => eq(k,v))
```

Whats wrong with the above code? `flatMap` expects a one argument function and here i am passing one argument which is a Pair of integers.

Also this works

```
m.flatMap {
   case (k,v) => eq(k,v)
}
```

but this does not

```
m.flatMap {
      (k,v) => eq(k,v)
}
```

Looks like i am missing something. Help?

Comment: thanks that bugged me for a long time

Answer (score 7):

There is no such syntax:

```
m.flatMap((k,v) => eq(k,v))
```

Well, in fact there is such syntax, but actually it is used in functions that accept two arguments (like reduce):

```
List(1,2,3,4).reduce((acc, x) => acc + x)
```

The

```
m.flatMap {
   case (k,v) => eq(k,v)
}
```

syntax works because in fact it is something like this:

```
val temp: PartialFunction[Tuple2[X,Y], Tuple2[Y,X]] = { 
   case (k,v) => eq(k,v) // using literal expression to construct function
} 

m.flatMap(temp) // with braces ommited
```

They key thing here is the usage of `case` word (actually, there is a discussion to enable your very syntax) [which turns usual braces expression](https://iainmcgin.github.io/scala-ref-markdown/ScalaReference-mathml.html#pattern-matching-anonymous-functions), like `{ ... }` into full blown anonymous partial function

Answer (score 6):

(If you want to simply fix the error you're getting, see the 2nd solution (with `flatMap`); if you want a generally nicer solution, read from the beginning.)

**What you need instead is `filter` not `flatMap`:**

```
def eq(k: Int, v: Int) = k == v

val m = Map(1->2, 3->4, 5->6, 7->8, 4->4, 9->9, 10->12, 11->11)

m.filter((eq _).tupled)
```

...which of course reduces to just the following, without the need for `eq`:

```
m.filter { case (k, v) => k == v }
```

**result:**

```
Map(9 -> 9, 11 -> 11, 4 -> 4)
```

**OR... If you want to stick with `flatMap`**

First you must know that `flatMap` will pass to your function TUPLES not keys and values as separate arguments.

Additionally, you must change the `Option` returned by `eq` to something that can be fed back to `flatMap` on sequences such as `List` or `Map` (actually any `GenTraversableOnce` to be precise):

```
def eq(k: Int, v: Int) = if (k == v) List(k -> v) else Nil

m.flatMap { case (k,v) => eq(k,v) } // use pattern matching to unpack the tuple
```

or the uglier but equivalent:

```
m.flatMap { x => eq(x._1, x._2) }
```

alternatively, you can convert `eq` to take a tuple instead:

```
m.flatMap((eq _).tupled)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that what you want is a single argument that will be a couple, not two arguments. Something like this may work

```
m.flatMap(k => eq(k._1, k._2))
```

The code snippet that works uses pattern matching. You give names to both elements of your couple. It's a partial function and can be use here in your flatMap.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do:

```
m.flatMap { case (k,v) => eq(k,v) }
```

Note that here I switch to curly braces, which indicates a function block rather than parameters, and the function here is a case statement. This means that the function block I'm passing to `flatMap` is a *partialFunction* that is only invoked for items that match the case statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your `eq` function takes two parameters, that is why you are getting the type error. Try:

```
def f(p: (Int, Int)) = if (p._1 == p._2) Some(p) else None
m flatMap f
```